# Need to arrange tuples in a list as per another list tuple indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, list-comprehension

```
Source = [('A','B','IP1','N1'),('K','G','IP2','N2'),('K','L','IP3','N3') ('W','T','IP4','N4') ]
Target = [('B','A','IP5','N5'), ('T','W','IP6','N6')]
```

Here you can observe 1st two characters in each tuple of `Target` list were reverse to `Source` tuples, so i need to make `Target` list as

```
Re_Target = [('B','A','IP5','N5'),('G','K'),('L','K') ('T','W','IP6','N6')]
```

Here 1st and last tuples of `Re_Target` list indices are same as 1st and last tuples of Source as it looks like the reverse combination and if there is no reverse combi then add reverse with no `'IP'` and `'N'` in the tuple just like for `('K','G','IP2','N2'),('K','L','IP3','N3') -> ('G','K'),('L','K')`

Note: Shouldn't use nested for loop or itertools as it is very slow for my data which will be having 7000 tuples, and in place of 'A', 'B','K', 'G',.. it can be anything.

Comment: Can u explaind yourself better?

Comment: Please be more clear with the inputs and expected outputs of your function. Also, can you show us what you've tried, and what specific improvements you'd like to make to it?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the goal is to find the reversed `Source` tuples (first two characters) that are not in the `Target` tuples, and add them.  You can first get the sets of reversed, two-character `Source` tuples and unreversed `Target` tuples:

```
source_tuples = set([s[:2][::-1] for s in Source])
target_tuples = set([t[:2] for t in Target])
```

Then you can identify which tuples are not in the `Target` list by taking the difference, then adding them to the `Target` list.

```
missing_target_tuples = list(source_tuples - target_tuples)
Target.extend(missing_target_tuples)
```

It looks like they need to be sorted, so that can be the final step when reassigning it to `Re_Target`.

```
Re_Target = sorted(Target)
```

Full code:

```
Source = [('A','B','IP1','N1'),('K','G','IP2','N2'),('K','L','IP3','N3'), ('W','T','IP4','N4') ]
Target = [('B','A','IP5','N5'), ('T','W','IP6','N6')]
source_tuples = set([s[:2][::-1] for s in Source])
target_tuples = set([t[:2] for t in Target])
missed_target_tuples = list(source_tuples - target_tuples)
Target.extend(missed_target_tuples)
Re_Target = sorted(Target)

print(Re_Target)
# [('B', 'A', 'IP5', 'N5'), ('G', 'K'), ('L', 'K'), ('T', 'W', 'IP6', 'N6')]
```

Comment: Hi with this, Source and result have different index, but i want index to be same

Comment: That must mean there can be multiple instances of tuples, like `('A','B','IP1','N1')` and `('A','B','IP2','N2')`.  Is that correct?  Otherwise, this should result in the source and result having the same indices.

Comment: Source = [('32892', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'),
 ('32890', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'),
 ('32838', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113')]

Comment: Re_Target = [('32891', '32838'), ('32891', '32890'), ('32891', '32892')]

Comment: if we take, Target = []

Comment: Yeah it will have multiple instances of tuples with different IPs and Ns, like ('A','B','IP1','N1') and ('A','B','IP2','N2')

Comment: Re_Target should be: [ ('32891', '32892'),  ('32891', '32890'), ('32891', '32838')]

Comment: I went based on your example.  This new example you gave is in descending order, while original example is ascending order.  The sort can be changed to descending order by `Re_Target = sorted(Target, key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)`, but then the first example would be wrong.  This approach would not work for the additional criteria of matching a set with duplicate tuples or any arbitrary order.

Comment: Please don't consider list is in descending order or ascending order, bcz tuples may change any way like Source = [ ('32890', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'),('32892', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113'), ('32838', '32891', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-02', '10.88.163.113', 'HRSNNJAQ-vMME-01', '10.88.162.81', 'EKRGMD92-vMME-02', '10.88.159.113')]

Comment: So need to take indices of tuple in source and if need to put reversed tuple of target in same indices

Comment: Hi, thanks based on your answer i have added few more lines to make answer correct and posted solution

Answer (score 1):

i got it and the results are correct now:

```
def take_first(elem):
    return(elem[0], elem[1])
def take_second(elem):
    return(elem[1], elem[0])
Source = [('A','B','IP1','N1'),('K','G','IP2','N2'),('K','L','IP3','N3'), ('W','T','IP4','N4') ]
print(sorted(Source, key=take_second))
Target = [('B','A','IP5','N5'), ('T','W','IP6','N6')]
source_tuples = set([s[:2][::-1] for s in Source])
target_tuples = set([t[:2] for t in Target])
missed_target_tuples = list(source_tuples - target_tuples)
Target.extend(missed_target_tuples)
Re_Target = sorted(Target, key=take_first)
print(Re_Target)
```

Here i have added two functions:

```
def take_first(elem):
    return(elem[0], elem[1])
def take_second(elem):
    return(elem[1], elem[0])
```

and gave these functions as key to `sorted()` as

```
sorted(Source, key=take_second)
Re_Target = sorted(Target,key=take_first)
```